# kubernetes copy command does not respond

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-container

I want to copy one folder to pod, I am using below command 
`kubectl cp keys $POD:/home/oracle/`

Issue is when I hit enter, I do not see any response(it does not exit after copying folder), as if the command is taking long time, although when I check POD I can see folder is copied.

I need to close it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to execute next command.

below is debug log

```

```
kubectl cp test $POD:/home/oracle/ -v=8
 loader.go:357] Config loaded from file /root/.kube/config
 round_trippers.go:414] GET https://192.168.3.236:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/xnode-2-56cb894476-w9thk
 round_trippers.go:421] Request Headers:
 round_trippers.go:424]     Accept: application/json, */*
 round_trippers.go:424]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.9.5 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/f01a2bf
 round_trippers.go:439] Response Status: 200 OK in 25 milliseconds
 round_trippers.go:442] Response Headers:
 round_trippers.go:445]     Content-Type: application/json
 round_trippers.go:445]     Content-Length: 2594
 round_trippers.go:445]     Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2018 03:34:50 GMT
 request.go:873] Response Body: {"kind":"Pod","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"xnode-2-56cb894476-w9thk","generateName":"xnode-2-56cb894476-","namespace":"default","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/xnode-2-56cb894476-w9thk","uid":"bd88c607-2db6-11e8-aa6f-525400ddd5c6","resourceVersion":"1213768","creationTimestamp":"2018-03-22T09:52:32Z","labels":{"pod-template-hash":"1276450032","run":"xnode-2"},"ownerReferences":[{"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"ReplicaSet","name":"xnode-2-56cb894476","uid":"bd78a06e-2db6-11e8-aa6f-525400ddd5c6","controller":true,"blockOwnerDeletion":true}]},"spec":{"volumes":[{"name":"default-token-mf6z4","secret":{"secretName":"default-token-mf6z4","defaultMode":420}}],"containers":[{"name":"xnode-2","image":"engg-nexus.com:8511/ms-linux","args":["/bin/bash"],"env":[{"name":"JAVA_HOME","value":"/usr/orps/java/jdk1.8.0_144"},{"name":"DISPLAY","value":":1"}],"resources":{},"volumeMounts":[{"name":"default-token-mf6z4","readOnly":true,"mountPath":"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/s [truncated 1570 chars]
 round_trippers.go:414] POST https://192.168.3.236:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/xnode-2-56cb894476-w9thk/exec?command=test&command=-d&command=%2Fhome%2Foracle%2F%2Fconfig&container=xnode-2&container=xnode-2&stderr=true&stdout=true
 round_trippers.go:421] Request Headers:
 round_trippers.go:424]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v4.channel.k8s.io
 round_trippers.go:424]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v3.channel.k8s.io
 round_trippers.go:424]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v2.channel.k8s.io
 round_trippers.go:424]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: channel.k8s.io
 round_trippers.go:424]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.9.5 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/f01a2bf
 round_trippers.go:439] Response Status: 101 Switching Protocols in 75 milliseconds
 round_trippers.go:442] Response Headers:
 round_trippers.go:445]     Connection: Upgrade
 round_trippers.go:445]     Upgrade: SPDY/3.1
 round_trippers.go:445]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v4.channel.k8s.io
 round_trippers.go:445]     Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2018 03:34:50 GMT
 round_trippers.go:414] GET https://192.168.3.236:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/xnode-2-56cb894476-w9thk
 round_trippers.go:421] Request Headers:
 round_trippers.go:424]     Accept: application/json, */*
 round_trippers.go:424]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.9.5 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/f01a2bf
 round_trippers.go:439] Response Status: 200 OK in 4 milliseconds
 round_trippers.go:442] Response Headers:
 round_trippers.go:445]     Content-Length: 2594
 round_trippers.go:445]     Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2018 03:34:50 GMT
 round_trippers.go:445]     Content-Type: application/json
 request.go:873] Response Body: {"kind":"Pod","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"xnode-2-56cb894476-w9thk","generateName":"xnode-2-56cb894476-","namespace":"default","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/xnode-2-56cb894476-w9thk","uid":"bd88c607-2db6-11e8-aa6f-525400ddd5c6","resourceVersion":"1213768","creationTimestamp":"2018-03-22T09:52:32Z","labels":{"pod-template-hash":"1276450032","run":"xnode-2"},"ownerReferences":[{"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"ReplicaSet","name":"xnode-2-56cb894476","uid":"bd78a06e-2db6-11e8-aa6f-525400ddd5c6","controller":true,"blockOwnerDeletion":true}]},"spec":{"volumes":[{"name":"default-token-mf6z4","secret":{"secretName":"default-token-mf6z4","defaultMode":420}}],"containers":[{"name":"xnode-2","image":"engg-nexus.com:8511/ms-linux","args":["/bin/bash"],"env":[{"name":"JAVA_HOME","value":"/usr/orps/java/jdk1.8.0_144"},{"name":"DISPLAY","value":":1"}],"resources":{},"volumeMounts":[{"name":"default-token-mf6z4","readOnly":true,"mountPath":"/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/s [truncated 1570 chars]
 round_trippers.go:414] POST https://192.168.3.236:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/xnode-2-56cb894476-w9thk/exec?command=tar&command=xf&command=-&command=-C&command=%2Fhome%2Foracle%2F%2Fconfig&container=xnode-2&container=xnode-2&stderr=true&stdin=true&stdout=true
 round_trippers.go:421] Request Headers:
 round_trippers.go:424]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v4.channel.k8s.io
 round_trippers.go:424]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v3.channel.k8s.io
 round_trippers.go:424]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v2.channel.k8s.io
 round_trippers.go:424]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: channel.k8s.io
 round_trippers.go:424]     User-Agent: kubectl/v1.9.5 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/f01a2bf
 round_trippers.go:439] Response Status: 101 Switching Protocols in 69 milliseconds
 round_trippers.go:442] Response Headers:
 round_trippers.go:445]     Connection: Upgrade
 round_trippers.go:445]     Upgrade: SPDY/3.1
 round_trippers.go:445]     X-Stream-Protocol-Version: v4.channel.k8s.io
 round_trippers.go:445]     Date: Fri, 23 Mar 2018 03:34:50 GMT
```

```

Comment: Can you call that command with a `debug` flag, remove sensitive information like token and show a result `kubectl cp keys $POD:/home/oracle/ -v=8`?

Comment: What version of docker are you running?

Comment: @JordanLiggitt Version : 1.13.1

Comment: @AntonKostenko I have updated log in my question.

Comment: @Dhananjay your command looks right and in a shared part of logs (that is not a full log, yes?) I don't see any troubles. Can your try to run that command with full path, e.g. `kubectl cp /full/path $POD:/home/oracle/`. And please make sure that you have read rights to a source directory and it is containing some files.

Comment: @Anton i tried full path to source directory but still sometime command completes and sometimes it hangs.

Comment: @Dhananjay so output of the command (without `-v` flag) is just nothing?

Comment: Yes, cursor just freezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to a bug in the docker client that results in the client side not closing the input stream.

See https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36516 for the docker issue and  https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/61557 for the impact on kubectl